# Fastest way to get all unique numbers between two different dimension numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of varying dimensions, and I need to get all unique ints between them both.

Since they are of varying dimensions, I decided to get the unique numbers for each of them, concatenate them, and then get the unique values for that.

Initial approach

```
import numpy as np
import time

array1 = np.random.randint(1, high=5000, size=(512, 4) , dtype=np.int32)
array2 = np.random.randint(1, high=5000, size=(512, 64) , dtype=np.int32)

start = time.time()
np.unique( np.concatenate( [np.unique(array1), np.unique(array2)] ) )
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Output (average out of 5):

> 0.011

Environment: Google Colab

Is there a faster way?

My guess would be to perform only one np.unique operation, doing that with different sized numpy arrays is the challenge of that.

Comment: Could you update the numbers in your code to be representative of your actual data that you suggested to Paul please?

Comment: It seems faster on my Mac at least to run `np.unique()` on the concatenated, flattened arrays... `np.unique(np.concatenate( (array1, array2), axis=None))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ints don't spread too far there is indeed a faster approach. The code below assumes for simplicity nonnegative ints 
smaller than 5000.

```
def use_mask():
    mask = np.zeros(5000,bool)
    mask[array1] = True
    mask[array2] = True
    return np.where(mask)
```

To make this a proper function you'd have to find the min and max of array1/2 combined, take the difference, fall back to something else if it is too large, otherwise subtract the min from array1/2 and proceed more or less like I did.

Comment: In my real case, it'll be random ints from 1 to 10 million

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 How large (#elements) will the real arrays be?

Comment: for number of arrays, they will be 64 to 5000, for the dimension of those arrays, they will be 132 to 1024

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 10,000,000 labels is still doable with this method. The more array elements the faster it becomes compared with `np.unique`. You'd have to check whether it speeds things up for you. My guess would be yes.

Answer (score 1):

`np.hstack` will work slightly faster than your initial approach (though the difference is not greatly significant):

```
In [129]: %timeit np.unique(np.concatenate([np.unique(array1), np.unique(array2)]))                                      
1.74 ms ± 2.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [130]: %timeit np.unique(np.hstack((array1, array2)))                                                                 
1.58 ms ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```